# Rails generates wrong asset url in production (with localhost instead of server ip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 6 in production generates wrong asset path url with http://localhost:3000/xxxxxx

When I replace http://localhost:3000 with server IP assets load fine, so it's just url generation error by rails.

System is run on digital ocean with Passanger on Nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `config.action_controller.asset_host = "assets.example.com"` to  `/config/environments/production.rb`